# If $f: \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R $ is monotonic and onto, prove that $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f: \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R $ is monotonic and onto, prove that $f$ is continuous. (Hint: given any $x \in \Bbb R$ and any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is $x_1$ with $f(x_1)= f(x) - \epsilon$ and $f(x_2) = f(x) +\epsilon. $Use this to get $\delta \gt 0$.)

I need to show if $\exists \delta \gt 0: |x-a|\lt \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(a)| \lt \epsilon $

$f(x_1) \lt f(x) \lt f(x_2)$ is all I can come up with.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I have no idea where to go from $f(x_1) \lt f(x) \lt  f(x_2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**
You are right, $f(x_1) < f(x) < f(x_2)$. Consider using
$$
\delta = \max\{x-x_1, x_2-x\}
$$

What can you say about $f(z)$ for any $z \in (x-\delta, x+\delta)$?

Comment: it will still be between $f(x_1$) and $ f(x_2)$, right?

Comment: @Tim yes, what can you say about $|f(z) - f(x)|$?